# Why my sorting code does not work properly?

Tags: java, sorting

I have an array of ints and i need to: sort first half ascending and sort the other half descending. I don't know which is the reason that this won't work as i want.

```
        for(i = 0 ; i < array.length/2 - 1 ; i++){
            ok = false;
            for(j = i ; j < array.length/2 - 1 ; j++){
                if(array[j]>array[j+1]){
                    tempValue = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j+1];
                    array[j+1] = tempValue;
                    ok = true;
                }
            }
            if(ok == false)
                break;
        }

        for(i = array.length/2 ; i < array.length - 1 ; i++){
            ok = false;
            for(j = i ; j < array.length - 1; j++){
                if(array[j]<array[j+1]){
                    tempValue = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j+1];
                    array[j+1] = tempValue;
                    ok = false;
                }
            }
             if(ok == false)
                 break;
        }

Expected result: [4,1,2,5,6,8,7,9] - > [1,2,4,5,9,8,7,6].

Result in my code: [1,2,4,5,8,7,9,6].
```

Comment: Have you tried **debugging** the code?

Comment: Currently i'm writing in an online compiler, so i don't have access to a debugger.

Comment: Then I suggest you wait until you have a debugger, then debug the code yourself, instead of asking us to debug it for you. --- Until then, reacquaint yourself with how Bubblesort works. If you iterate from low index to high index, you end up moving the largest value (or smallest if sorting descending) to the end, so on second iteration you can skip the *last* element in your comparisons, not the *first* element, which is what your code is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was multiple errors in your code.
The major was `ok=false` when you're sorting the other half array.
The below code is working fine.

```
 public class MyClass {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            int i,j,tempValue;
            int array[]= {4,1,2,5,3,6,8,7,10,9};
            boolean ok=true;

            for(i = 0 ; i < array.length/2  ; i++){
                    ok = false;
                    for(j = i ; j < array.length/2  ; j++){
                        if(array[j]>array[j+1]){
                            tempValue = array[j];
                            array[j] = array[j+1];
                            array[j+1] = tempValue;
                            ok = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if(ok == false)
                        break;
                }
                for(i = array.length/2 ; i < array.length  ; i++){
                    ok = false;
                    for(j = array.length/2 ; j < array.length - 1; j++){
                        if(array[j]<array[j+1]){
                            tempValue = array[j];
                            array[j] = array[j+1];
                            array[j+1] = tempValue;
                            ok = true;
                        }
                    }
                     if(ok == false)
                         break;
                }

        for(i = 0 ; i < array.length  ; i++){
        System.out.print(array[i]);
      }
        }
    }
```